# Is it possible to migrate the data from an old version of rocket.chat to a new version running with snaps?

Tags: rocket.chat

I have an old version (0.17) of rocket.chat running on Ubuntu(14.04.5). Is it possible to migrate the data to a new version running with snaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing data into snaps is technically possible.  But very complicated right now.  Some effort is currently underway to make it extremely simple to import data.

In the mean time I would suggest upgrading to a newer version of Rocket.Chat to make that transition easier.

To upgrade you need to first update your version of Node.js.
Install `n` via `npm install -g n` then perform the upgrade to Node.js 4.5 by running: `n 4.5`

Now you'll need to grab the latest version of Rocket.Chat and install it. You'll pretty much repeat the install step from what ever guide you followed.  A great guide is also available [here](https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/ubuntu/#install)

Answer (score 0):

You should read the Rocket Chat upgrade guide: https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/updating/from-0-x-x-to-0-40-0/.